# onClick animation not trigerring

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So the problem I am having is this, here I have a pushLogic, so the thing  I am trying to achieve is this, when I press the button I wanna start the animation, I want spinner to start spinning but for some reason it is not doing it.

```
  const [spinnerOne, setSpinnerOne] = useState(true);

  const push= ()=>{ 
    setSpinnerOne(true)
    setTimeout(()=>{
     history.push('/')
    },3000)
 
 }
  return (
     <div>
       <span className={spinnerOne  ? `spinnerOne` :''}></span>
       <button onClick={push} ></button>
    </div>
```

css

```
@keyframes spinnerOne {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.spinnerOne:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -120px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #b409ca;
  border-top-color: #3500c8;
  border-right-color: rgb(221, 7, 0);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(246, 98, 0);
  animation: spinnerOne 2s linear infinite
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate out the spinner css class from the animation css class, and apply the animation class onClick.

```
export default function App() {
   const [spinnerOne, setSpinnerOne] = useState(false);

  const push= ()=>{ 
    setSpinnerOne(true)
    setTimeout(()=>{
     //history.push('/')
    },3000)
 
 }
  return (
     <div>
       <span className={spinnerOne  ? `spinner spinnerOne` :'spinner'}></span>
       <button onClick={push} >Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

css

```
.spinner:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -120px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #b409ca;
  border-top-color: #3500c8;
  border-right-color: rgb(221, 7, 0);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(246, 98, 0);
}

.spinnerOne:before {
  animation: spinnerOne 2s linear infinite
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bvcnru?file=src/App.js

Comment: I want to spinner be visible on the initial render, and then spin onClick